# "Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None" Django and AJAX

Tags: python, jquery, json, django, django-rest-framework

I’m trying to build a web app using Django and I want to upload a file (a pdf or word document) using ajax (the ajax module in jquery).

I’m building my API using the django-rest-framework.

I’ve pretty much tried to do what every site says but can’t seem to get around it.

Has anyone done this?

My views:

```
def contract_post(request):

contract = Contract()

if request.method == 'POST':
serializer = ContractSerializer(contract, data=request.data)
data = {}
if serializer.is_valid():
serializer.create(validated_data=request.data)
handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['atasament'])
return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

def handle_uploaded_file(f):
with open(f.name, 'wb+') as destination:
for chunk in f.chunks():
destination.write(chunk)
```

My serializer (it's a nested serializer):

```
class ContractSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
client = ClientSerializer(read_only=False)
termen = serializers.DateField(format='%Y-%m-%d', default=datetime.date.today)
atasament = serializers.FileField(max_length=None, allow_empty_file=True)
class Meta:
model = Contract
fields = (
'pk',
'tip',
'nr_data',
'obiectul',
'termen',
'atasament',
'client',
)

def create(self, validated_data):
client = validated_data.pop('client')
client_instance, created = Client.objects.get_or_create(**client)
contract_instance = Contract.objects.create(**validated_data, client=client_instance)
return client_instance
```

My model:

```
class Contract(models.Model):
TIPURI = (
('P', 'Proiectare'),
('E', 'Executie'),
('D', 'Documentatie'),
)
tip = models.CharField(max_length=300, choices=TIPURI)
nr_data = models.CharField(max_length=50)
obiectul = models.TextField()
termen = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
atasament = models.FileField(upload_to='main/documents/', blank=True, null=True)
client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
def __str__(self):
return self.nr_data

class Meta:
verbose_name_plural = "Contracte"
```

My JS:

```
$('#form_add').submit(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();

let input_atasament = document.getElementById('input_atasament');
let client_pk = $("#input_clienti").val();
let nr_data = "test";
let tip = $("#input_tip").val();
let obiectul = $("#input_obiectul").val();
let termen = $("#input_termen").val();
const url = \/api/contract-post/`;let client_url = `/api/client-get/${client_pk}`;let client = $.ajax({url: client_url,async: false,dataType: 'json'}).responseJSON;`

let data = new FormData();
data.append('nr_data', "test");
data.append('tip', tip);
data.append('obiectul', obiectul);
data.append('termen', termen);
data.append('atasament', input_atasament.files[0]);
data.append('client', JSON.stringify(client));
var action = function(d) {
console.log(d);
};
$.ajax({
url: url,
headers: {
'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrftoken,
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
},
data: data,
type: "POST",
contentType: false,
processData: false,
success: action,
error: action
});

});
```

And what error I get now:

> "Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None"

Comment: do u have a form element in your HTML?

Comment: Yes I have a form element.

Comment: can you share your form element?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/RpfrMmvH here is a paste bin link with my form element. If you think it will help I can link you my git repo too.

Comment: You have a typo in your form tag closing tag </from>

Comment: Not a fix to the error obviously, but perhaps you could format indentation to make the code more readable?

Comment: Sorry for that, I didn't even realize when I posted it.